# How to set a default selection in p-dropdown in a reactive form

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using `"primeng": "^14.1.1"` with Angular 14. I'm creating a reactive form. There is a dropdown which will have only two options viz. "Yes" and "No". When the page loads my dropdown is blank. Though both the options comes in dropdown on clicking but initially its blank. This is what I tried. I tried both:

1. NgModel
2. formControlName

**Try 1: Setting default value using ngModel variable**

```
<p-dropdown 
  [options]="taxOrNoTax"  // Options "YES" and "NO"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedtaxOrNoTax" // ngModel to track selected value
  optionLabel="name"
  formControlName="leTaxNoTax" // form control variable
>
</p-dropdown>


taxOrNoTax: any[] = [];
selectedtaxOrNoTax: any;

this._myService.getData(...)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        data.map((item: any) => {
          this.taxOrNoTax.push({ // filling up dropdown options
          name: item.name,
          value: item.name.charAt(0),
          });
        });
      });

//setting default value using only ngModel variable
this.selectedtaxOrNoTax = [{ name: 'Yes', value: 'Y' }];

this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    ...
    leTaxNoTax: new FormControl(),
    ...
})
```

**Try 2: Setting default value in only FormGroup**

```
// same code as above but
      leTaxNoTax: new FormControl({
        value: { name: 'Yes', value: 'Y' },
        disabled: true,
      }),
```

I also tried setting in both FormGroup and ngModel variable together but still its blank on load. Please picth in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use optionLabel and optionValue ?
if you specify the option value then you can set your formControl with initial value ex: 'Y',
and the label will be 'Yes',

```html
<p-dropdown 
  [options]="taxOrNoTax"  // Options "YES" and "NO"
  optionLabel="name"
  optionValue="value"
  formControlName="leTaxNoTax" // form control variable
>
</p-dropdown>
```

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    ...
    leTaxNoTax: new FormControl({value:'Y'}),
    ...
})
```

- and remove [(ngModel)]